# Nexus: error NU1301: Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk' from remote source

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, nuget, nexus, nexus3

I have upgraded my Nexus from `3.29.0` to `3.58.1` via Terraform using Helm Kubernetes cluster and I am getting the following error now:

```
[2023-08-14T08:05:46.935Z] C:\Users\Deployer\workspace\MyApp\MyApp.View.Test.csproj : error NU1301: Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk' from remote source 'https://mynexus.com/repository/nuget-group/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'. [C:\Users\Deployer\workspace\MyApp\myapp.sln]
```

I didn't change anything on any of the nuget-repository, nuget-group and nuget-proxy.

Why am I getting this error? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the `Protocol Version` for `nuget-proxy` to `NuGet V2`. It got set to `NuGet V3` after the Nexus upgrade.

Reference Screenshot below:

[image]

In your Terraform code, if you're using `nexus_repository_nuget_proxy` then change your code as follows:

```
resource "nexus_repository_nuget_proxy" "nuget_proxy" {
...
  query_cache_item_max_age = 1440
  nuget_version            = "V2"
...
}
```

In your Terraform code, if you're using `nexus_repository` then change your code as follows:

```
resource "nexus_repository" "nuget_proxy" {
...
  nuget_proxy {
    query_cache_item_max_age = 1440
    nuget_version            = "V2"
  }
...
}
```